# "No database type set, using meta data indicating: SQLSERVER" Springbatch SQLSERVER

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot

Estoy iniciando mi aplicacion con springbatch pero me dice "No database type set, using meta data indicating: SQLSERVER he buscado en internet y uso la misma config que muchas ejemplos en mi properties que es la siguiente:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=FacturaDB
spring.datasource.username=dbnameroot
spring.datasource.password=Testpass123
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
IntegratedSecurity = true
```